# why "if" condition is ignored?

Tags: node.js, json, server

when I run this server on postman, I'm getting "error login" but it should return "success".
but when i do add console.log(body.req) then on terminal I'm gettting "name, email,password", which i passed in body.
and also when I do `console.log(req.body.name===database.users[0].name && req.body.email===database.users[0].email, req.body, database);`
then in terminal I'm getting all data from database but for "If" it is returning false.

```
 const bodyParser=require('body-parser');   
 const app=express();
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false}));

 const database= {
     users : [
         {
          id: '123',
          name: 'amit',
          email :'amitrk@gmail.com',
          password:'123',
          entries:'0',
           joined: new Date()
         },
         /*{
            id: '124',
          name:'Rahul',
          email :'amit@gmail.com',
          password:'54858',
          entries:'0',
           joined: new Date() 
         },*/
     ]
     
 }
   /*const app=express();
   app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
        res.send("this is working");
   })*/
    app.post('/signin',(req,res)=>{
         //console.log(req.body);
      if(req.body.name===database.users[0].name && req.body.email===database.users[0].email) {
           console.log("sucess");
      }
       else {
           res.status(400).json("error login");
       }
    })
   app.listen(3000,()=>{
        console.log("app is running on port");
   })
```

Comment: Try doing a little more debugging, like console.log(req.body.name); console.log(req.body.name===database.users[0].name); etc.  to see exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: We cannot possibly assist you in any helpful fashion without seeing your client-side code that's invoking this route as a [mre].

Comment: Here is the code where I'm getting errors, Basically it is  ignoring the "IF" statement  and returning else statement, which I don't want

Comment: app.post('/signin',(req,res)=>{
         //console.log(req.body.name);
      if(req.body.name===database.users[0].name && req.body.email===database.users[0].email) {
           console.log("sucess");
      }
       else {
           res.status(400).json("error login");
       }
    })

Comment: It's probably whitespace. By far, the **fastest** way to solve this is to use the debugger built into your IDE or browser. (Yes, you can run Node.js code in a debugger in an IDE, or even by using [the devtools of your browser](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/).) Fundamentally, the strings don't match. We can't tell you why. Your debugger can.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't appear to be sending a response in the if condition. What this will do, if the control went to your if condition, is print 'success' on console, but not send any response (i.e. hang the request).

Secondly, is this exactly the code you ran? Did you have password check in the if condition as well? Do note that when using `===`, '123' is not equal to 123.

These are the only clues, I can provide from what was shared. You can share the postman request body, which might have more clues.